# How to add new columns in group price section in magento

Tags: magento, admin, addition, multiple-columns, product

I need to add **2 new columns** in magento admin in the group price section.

I have checked the template file.

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml
```

I have added  new columns there, but..

**how can i add these two columns in database and save values.**

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue. Answer by Samuel Coman was great help for me. To be more precise, you have to modify three files. I have added integer column 'popularity' (to be used by xml-rpc methods), but rules are the same. Here is my example.

**The first file**

```
magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml
```

in table around line 50 add new `<th>`:

```
<th><?php echo $this->getPriceColumnHeader(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Popularity')); ?></th>
```

in `var groupPriceRowTemplate` around line 67 add new `<td>`:

```
+ '<td><input class="<?php echo $_htmlClass; ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][popularity]" value="{{popularity}}" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_popularity"/></td>'
```

in `var groupPriceControl` line 95 modify default arguments etc.:

```
    var data = {
        website_id: '<?php echo $this->getDefaultWebsite(); ?>',
        group: '<?php echo $this->getDefaultCustomerGroup(); ?>',
        price: '',
        popularity: '',
        readOnly: false,
        index: this.itemsCount++
    };

    if(arguments.length >= 3) {
        data.website_id = arguments[0];
        data.group = arguments[1];
        data.price = arguments[2];
        data.popularity = arguments[3];
    }
    if (arguments.length == 5) {
        data.readOnly = arguments[4];
    }
```

add your column in `addItem` call, line 165:

```
groupPriceControl.addItem('<?php echo $_item['website_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $_item['cust_group']; ?>', '<?php echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']); ?>', '<?php echo sprintf('%.0f', $_item['popularity']); ?>', <?php echo (int)!empty($_item['readonly']); ?>);
```

**The second file**
    magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Groupprice/Abstract.php

here you have to modify `afterSave` method, firstly add your column to the array `$new`, line 316:

```
        $new[$key] = array_merge(array(
            'website_id'        => $data['website_id'],
            'all_groups'        => $useForAllGroups ? 1 : 0,
            'customer_group_id' => $customerGroupId,
            'value'             => $data['price'],
            'popularity'        => $data['popularity'],
        ), $this->_getAdditionalUniqueFields($data));
```

then you have to handle a case when you only change your new column and save it, so on line 349, after `if (!empty($update))` statement, goes:

```
    if (!empty($update)) {
        foreach ($update as $k => $v) {
            if ($old[$k]['price'] != $v['value'] || $old[$k]['popularity'] != $v['popularity']) {
                $price = new Varien_Object(array(
                    'value_id'  => $old[$k]['price_id'],
                    'value'     => $v['value'],
                    'popularity'=> $v['popularity'],
                ));
                $this->_getResource()->savePriceData($price);

                $isChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**The third file**

```
magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Groupprice/Abstract.php
```

here modify `loadPriceData` method to properly show values from database; you have to just add your column to `$colums` variable, line 49:

```
    $columns = array(
        'price_id'      => $this->getIdFieldName(),
        'website_id'    => 'website_id',
        'all_groups'    => 'all_groups',
        'cust_group'    => 'customer_group_id',
        'price'         => 'value',
        'popularity'    => 'popularity',
    );
```

There is no need to change `savePriceData` method, as `_prepareDataForTable` inside it will find your new columns in database.

Than you have to add your columns to group prices table and also to tier price table, because it uses the same save methods, so run in mysql on your database commands similar to the following:

```
alter table catalog_product_entity_group_price add popularity integer;
alter table catalog_product_entity_tier_price add popularity integer;
```

And last, but not least remember to refresh the cache - without doing this system won't find new columns.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

To add the column create a new module and inside the installer alter the table catalog_product_entity_group_price and add your desired columns.

To save & display the data...well, I hope you are pretty advanced of Magento overriding.

The file you mentioned takes some data from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Price_Group_Abstract` but the real data is taken using the `loadPriceData` from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract`

The prices are saved in method `afterSave` from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract` which calls `savePriceData` from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract`

You could try to override those methods but you might break some Magento stuff. Those prices are tied with the Indexers also. Another option would be to create a separate module, to add another observer on product save, save your data into a separate table and get it back using an extension of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Price_Group_Abstract`